# How to clear a Unix terminal while using prolog?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, prolog

I was wondering if there's a way to actually clear a terminal screen while inside gprolog. What I'm looking for is not only to have a clean-character-free screen, I'm also looking for the cursor to be on top again, just like when you type 'clear' or hit ctrl+L.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed. Which of the tags was the most offending one? or all three, [linux], [unix], [terminal]? Is it enough to remove one or more of these tags to get the question back up?

Comment: @Boris: This question was asked many times, and it never was closed.

Comment: @Boris: you can go to meta and discuss it there.

Answer (score 5):

Try the `shell/1` built-in predicate with the `clear` command as argument:

```
| ?- shell(clear).


yes
```